# stat command using sftp (mtime)

Tags: bash, sftp

I'm trying to write a bash script, which automates finding reports being uploaded to an ftp site.  I want to use the mtime (`stat -c %Y <file>`) in an `if` statement to test against a static time parameter for further processing.  Is there an analogous command while using sftp?  'stat ' doesn't work, nor does 'sftp stat ', both returning 'Invalid Command'.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OpenSSH `sftp`, the closest you can get is

```
ls -l /remote/path/to/file
```

If you have a shell access, use `ssh` instead:

```
ssh user@example.com stat /remote/path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to request and get shell access to the ftp.  Just as an aside to anyone who might read this down the road.  There is a tool that's part of Linux builds, called 'Inotify' which will notify or kick off another script after a file has been uploaded.